# text and textfield using grid layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

im trying to use the grid layout in flutter to display multiple components but i am having trouble doing it.

below is the current code that i have

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finsec/widget/text_form_field.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Simple Interest Calculator App',
    home: ThirdFragment(),
    theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
        accentColor: Colors.indigoAccent),
  ));
}

class ThirdFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ThirdFragmentState();
  }
}

class _ThirdFragmentState extends State<ThirdFragment> {

  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _currencies = ['Rupees', 'Dollars', 'Pounds'];
  final double _minimumPadding = 5.0;

  var _currentItemSelected = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentItemSelected = _currencies[0];
   // principalController.addListener(onChange);
  }




  TextEditingController principalController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController roiController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController termController = TextEditingController();

  var displayResult = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;

    return Scaffold(
//          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Simple Interest Calculator'),
      ),

      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          children: List.generate(2, (index) {
            return 
            Text(
                'Item $index',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
              );
          }),
        )
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

i am trying to have a text on the left side and a text input field on the right of the text. currently i am displaying text because i am not sure how to add the textfield.  Also, the spacing between the two text is too big and i want to reduce the spacing.  thanks in advance

here is my output so far

[image]

im looking for output like the one below. every textfield i add should line up one below the other and the text should be center between the textfield.
below is an example of what i am trying to accomplish. notice how the textfield
are lineup

[image]

Comment: why don't you use a List instead of a GridView/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an example achieving what you need using `ListView.builder` instead of `GridView` .

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Hint $index",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]);
            }),
      ),
```

In case you still need to use `GridView`, you can use the following logic :

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          children: List.generate(10, (index) {
            return index.isEven
                ? Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                  )
                : TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Hint $index",
                    ),
                  );
          }),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Hi Diegoveloper,  thanks for your help.  it looks good but the text and textfield are far apart.  I need the text and textfield only a few spaces away from each other. check the image i added.  how can i change the code to have both text and textfield only a few spaces again from each other?

Comment: Sure, check my updated code, the first one, I just added a flex value to '2' for the TextField and  maxLines: 1 for the Text